# Django Swagger Different HTTP methods for different API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, swagger-ui

I am documenting API using swagger for Django,  but I noticed that there are GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE methods for API even though I have specified in Django code only GET method. How can I remove unsupported HTTP methods for these API?

**Swagger version** : 0.3.5

Comment: Do you have the answer to this question? Thanks